# Cakephp breadcrumb

Tags: cakephp, html-helper, breadcrumbs

I am a Cakephp beginner

I am creating breadcrumbs from my website, I am not sure what is the difference between using HTML helper and Breadcrumb helper, Html helper seems easier to use, but it seems like I have to add each crumb to each page manually, please correct me if i am wrong.

When I was trying to use the Html helper, I put

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->getCrumbs(' > ', array( 'text' => 'Customers', 'url' => array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'index'), 'escape' => false)); ?>
```

in my index.ctp

then, i put

```
    <?php $this->Html->addCrumb('Add customer', 'Customers/add'); ?>
```

in add.ctp

the breadcrumb "Customer" appears on the index.ctp, but when i go to the add.ctp page, no breadcrumb is shown.

I tried putting

```
echo $this->Html->getCrumbs(' > ', 'Home');
```

in default.ctp, then the "Add customer" appears after the Home crumb

How can I make it so that, on the add.ctp , the breadcrumb shows like this:
Customers > Add customer

Answer (score 2):

You should take a better look at the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#creating-breadcrumb-trails-with-htmlhelper) in the cookbook, usually it's all there.

Steps are:

1. Create a place for cakePHP to display the breadcrubs in your **layout template**, not `index.ctp` using something like `echo $this->Html->getCrumbs(' > ', 'Home');`. You should find your default layout in `View/Layout/default.ctp`.
2. Add a trail in **each page** with something like `$this->Html->addCrumb('Add customer', 'Customers/add');` for `View/Customers/add.ctp`

This is all done by the HTML helper, there isn't any different (*official*) breadcrumb helper.